# Integrating with another Semantic Web source

Tags: java, sparql, semantic-web, jena

I want to try and integrate my rdf data which is in an .rdf file format with dbpedia so I can build make semantic knowledge of my rdf data. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this  within Jena and Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that Jena support the SPARQL 1.1 SERVICE keyword, that lets you query across a local RDF store, and DBpedia at the same time.

There's a very brief example given here: http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-overview/#sparql11-federated-query

Answer (score -1):

You might want to have a look at Freebase, which is a system dedicated to linking semantic data. See http://www.freebase.com/ for more info.

Comment: Freebase doesn't include DBpedia data